# Java command lastModified() not working in Clojure

Tags: file, clojure, io, java

I am trying to get the last modified time from a file in Clojure, by executing a Java command.
By using java.io.File.lastModified I am supposed to be able to get the UNIX-time, this does not work by execution of the script or in the REPL.

My code is:
        (java.io.File.lastModified "/home/lol/lolness.txt")

and my error is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.io.File.lastModified (NO_SOURCE_FILE:24)

(java.io.File.separator) works, however.

EDIT:
Clojure version 1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT
Java version OpenJDK 1.6.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lastModified` is a method of `java.io.File` objects. To access it in Clojure, use the following syntax:

```
(.lastModified (java.io.File. "/home/lol/lolness.txt"))
```

Note that the namespaces `clojure.contrib.java-utils` (1.1) / `clojure.java.io` (bleeding edge) provide a function `file` which makes the creation of `java.io.File` objects more convenient. Since you're on the bleeding edge, the following should work for you:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(.lastModified (io/file "/home/lol/lolness.txt"))
```